# Numerical method for harmonic oscillator with jumping constant

Tags: ode, numerics, differential-equations

Let $k_1 \neq k_2$ be positive reals, $t_0 > 0$ and consider the following Cauchy problem in $[0,+\infty)$:
\begin{cases}
y(t) + k(t)y''(t) = 0 \newline
y(0) = 1/\sqrt{k_1} \newline
y'(0) = 0,
\end{cases}
where
\begin{equation}
k(t) =
\begin{cases}
k_1 \hspace{1 cm} 0 \leq t \leq t_0 \newline
k_2 \hspace{1 cm} t > t_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

It is clear that there exists a unique $C^1$ solution $y$ in $[0,+\infty)$, obtained by gluing two smooth solutions of the equation in $[0,t_0]$ and $[t_0,+\infty)$. An explicit computation gives:
\begin{equation}
y(t) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k_1}} \mathrm{cos} \bigg(\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{k_1}} \bigg) \hspace{1 cm} 0 \leq t \leq t_0; \newline
A \ \mathrm{cos}\bigg( \dfrac{t}{\sqrt{k_2}} + \phi \bigg) \hspace{1 cm} t > t_0,
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $\phi$ are obtained imposing the $C^1$ condition. With further computations one discovers that the amplitude is constant, i.e. $A = 1/\sqrt{k_1}$, if and only if $t_0 = n \pi \sqrt{k_1}$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$.

I am searching for a good numerical method for the problem in the constant-amplitude case. I have tried several classical schemes, but I discovered that when $k_2 >> k_1$ the second amplitude also grows bigger. Any suggestion?

Comment: Try a symplectic integrator from DifferentialEquations.jl in Julia:  https://docs.sciml.ai/dev/ then use events to handle the jump. You can also specify that you want to integration steps to include $t_0$ so you hit the jump dead-on

Comment: @whpowell96 thank you, I'll have a look.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas